# Python: PyQt4 Py2exe

Tags: python, pyqt, py2exe

Greetings!

So I've made a Python application that uses the ever so great PyQt as it's interface. Now if I was to specify the --bundle 0 option for Py2Exe the resulting compiled executable file works fine! But with all the needed files, the folder gets cluttered up. So I tried passing 1 and 2 for the --bundle option. One packs everything into file file whilst the other packs everything except the Python dll. However both of those options results in the executable file exiting upon execution. No errors are chucked back.

Another question on stackoverflow said to supply the "--includes sip" parameter for py2exe however that does not solve this issue. The sip module was already being included in all builds of the application so I can't think it has anything to do with sip.

I've used procmon to monitor what the file did upon execution. Can anyone make light of this? http://www.sendspace.com/file/z67dox

Thanks bye!

Comment: You can always use PyInstaller!

Comment: I get a 'list index out of range' error with Pyinstaller.

Answer (score 0):

I know that even using raw win32ui with py2exe can cause problems. Seems like they could be related, but I don't know enough about the architecture of PyQt.

[Py2exeAndWin32ui](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeAndWin32ui)

Though I realise this wouldn't give you a neat solution even if it did help.