# py2exe failing with PyQt4 app only on bundling? [Win7 64-bit]

Tags: python, pyqt, py2exe

I hope this is not a repeat, since a few questions seem to cover the issue but none with conclusive answers.

> [Python: PyQt4 Py2exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640140/python-pyqt4-py2exe) - No answer

I've got a very simple script that launches a window with a "Hello World" QPushButton. Upon click, the application exits. Simple as can be.

Using a very barebones `setup.py`, I generate a `dist` folder which contains a ton of files. The application runs fine.

I went online and added the `'bundle_files':1` and `zipfile=None` lines to my script, and now instead of a ton of files I get a 22mb exe that fails silently when I attempt to execute it. No log files, no error messages, nothing. Just a second of hesitation and nothing.

Another inconclusive SO thread suggested that this was a problem with py2exe and Windows 64, but the contributor was unable to explain what was the issue or where he read about it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the version of pyexe for win64. Also, please check the version of py2exe depending on the Python version (you probably have 2.7 ?)

http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/files/py2exe/0.6.9/py2exe-0.6.9.win64-py2.7.amd64.exe/download?use_mirror=ignum&download=

Comment: I ended up using PyINstaller with reasonable success. I will get back here and mark the answer if it pans out though!